# My app crashes when trying to navigate to next activity after capturing image using Camera2 API for custom camera

Tags: android, overlay, android-camera2, segmentation-fault

I have used the sample code from Google for the Camera2 API - [Camera2 API sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Basic)

I've also added a rectangular overlay on the camera preview. I'm getting a SIGSEGV error when I try navigating to the next activity to display the captured image.

*I think the problem is arising because of the Canvas. I'm not sure, but a few answers here suggested that it could be the problem as I'm closing the camera before starting the intent to the next activity.*

The canvas is using the width and height of the `Preview` to draw the rectangle. Could this possibly be the problem when I close the Camera object?

Rectangle.java

```
package com.example.googlecamera2;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

public class Rectangle extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    Context context;
    int width;
    int height;

    public Rectangle(Context context, int width, int height) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
    }


    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(6);

        Log.e("RECT", width +" "+ height);
        Rect rect = new Rect(width/8, height/8, 7*width/8, 7*height/8);
        canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
    }
}
```

This is the method call which saves the image

```
        @Override
        public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {
            mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage(), mFile));

            closeCameraDevice();
            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), DisplayImage.class).putExtra("IMAGE", mFile.getPath()));
        }

    };
```

This is the `ImageSaver` method

```
    private class ImageSaver implements Runnable {

        /**
         * The JPEG image
         */
        private final Image mImage;
        /**
         * The file we save the image into.
         */
        private final File mFile;

        ImageSaver(Image image, File file) {
            mImage = image;
            mFile = file;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
//            System.gc();
            ByteBuffer buffer = mImage.getPlanes()[0].getBuffer();
            byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
            buffer.get(bytes);
            capturedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);

            // Rectangle is drawn by dividing the preview in 8 dimensions and the rectangle starts
            // on 2nd dimension and ends on 7th dimension so take 6 for dividing the width and height
            int left = capturedImage.getWidth() / 8;
            int top = capturedImage.getHeight() / 8;
            int cropWidth = 6*left;
            int cropHeight = 6*top;
            Matrix rotationMatrix = new Matrix();
            rotationMatrix.postRotate(90);

            Log.e("Image dim", capturedImage.getWidth()+" "+capturedImage.getHeight());
            Log.e("Crop dim", left+" "+top+" "+cropWidth+" "+cropHeight);

            croppedImage = Bitmap.createBitmap(capturedImage, left, top, cropWidth, cropHeight, rotationMatrix, false);

            //Destroy the original bitmap image
            capturedImage.recycle();

            FileOutputStream output = null;
            try {
                output = new FileOutputStream(mFile);
                croppedImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
                output.flush();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally
            {
                mImage.close();
                if (null != output)
                {
                    try {
                        output.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
```

I'm drawing the rectangle here and this method is called when `openCamera()`:

```
private void setUpCameraOutputs(int width, int height) {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) activity.getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
        try {
            for (String cameraId : manager.getCameraIdList()) {
                CameraCharacteristics characteristics
                        = manager.getCameraCharacteristics(cameraId);

                // We don't use a front facing camera in this sample.
                Integer facing = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING);
                if (facing != null && facing == CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING_FRONT) {
                    continue;
                }

                StreamConfigurationMap map = characteristics.get(
                        CameraCharacteristics.SCALER_STREAM_CONFIGURATION_MAP);
                if (map == null) {
                    continue;
                }

                // For still image captures, we use the largest available size.
                Size largest = Collections.max(
                        Arrays.asList(map.getOutputSizes(ImageFormat.JPEG)),
                        new CompareSizesByArea());
                mImageReader = ImageReader.newInstance(largest.getWidth(), largest.getHeight(),
                        ImageFormat.JPEG, /*maxImages*/1);
                mImageReader.setOnImageAvailableListener(
                        mOnImageAvailableListener, mBackgroundHandler);

                // Find out if we need to swap dimension to get the preview size relative to sensor
                // coordinate.
                int displayRotation = activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getRotation();
                //noinspection ConstantConditions
                mSensorOrientation = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.SENSOR_ORIENTATION);
                boolean swappedDimensions = false;
                switch (displayRotation) {
                    case Surface.ROTATION_0:
                    case Surface.ROTATION_180:
                        if (mSensorOrientation == 90 || mSensorOrientation == 270) {
                            swappedDimensions = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    case Surface.ROTATION_90:
                    case Surface.ROTATION_270:
                        if (mSensorOrientation == 0 || mSensorOrientation == 180) {
                            swappedDimensions = true;
                        }
                        break;
                    default:
                        Log.e(TAG, "Display rotation is invalid: " + displayRotation);
                }

                Point displaySize = new Point();
                activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
                int rotatedPreviewWidth = width;
                int rotatedPreviewHeight = height;
                int maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.x;
                int maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.y;

                if (swappedDimensions) {
                    rotatedPreviewWidth = height;
                    rotatedPreviewHeight = width;
                    maxPreviewWidth = displaySize.y;
                    maxPreviewHeight = displaySize.x;
                }

                if (maxPreviewWidth > MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH) {
                    maxPreviewWidth = MAX_PREVIEW_WIDTH;
                }

                if (maxPreviewHeight > MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT) {
                    maxPreviewHeight = MAX_PREVIEW_HEIGHT;
                }

                // Danger, W.R.! Attempting to use too large a preview size could  exceed the camera
                // bus' bandwidth limitation, resulting in gorgeous previews but the storage of
                // garbage capture data.
                mPreviewSize = chooseOptimalSize(map.getOutputSizes(SurfaceTexture.class),
                        rotatedPreviewWidth, rotatedPreviewHeight, maxPreviewWidth,
                        maxPreviewHeight, largest);

                // We fit the aspect ratio of TextureView to the size of preview we picked.
                int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
                if (orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                            mPreviewSize.getWidth(), mPreviewSize.getHeight());
                } else {
                    mTextureView.setAspectRatio(
                            mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
                }

                // Add rectangle to the view
                Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(getActivity(), mPreviewSize.getHeight(), mPreviewSize.getWidth());
                linearLayout.addView(rectangle);

                // Check if the flash is supported.
                Boolean available = characteristics.get(CameraCharacteristics.FLASH_INFO_AVAILABLE);
                mFlashSupported = available == null ? false : available;

                mCameraId = cameraId;
                return;
            }
        } catch (CameraAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            // Currently an NPE is thrown when the Camera2API is used but not supported on the
            // device this code runs.
            ErrorDialog.newInstance(getString(R.string.camera_error))
                    .show(getChildFragmentManager(), FRAGMENT_DIALOG);
        }
    }
```

Stack Trace

```
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.googlecamera2-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.googlecamera2-1@split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.googlecamera2-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.googlecamera2-1@split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.googlecamera2-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.googlecamera2-1@split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.googlecamera2-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.googlecamera2-1@split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.googlecamera2-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.googlecamera2-1@split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.googlecamera2-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.googlecamera2-1@split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.googlecamera2-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.googlecamera2-1@split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.googlecamera2-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.googlecamera2-1@split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/art: Failed execv(/system/bin/dex2oat --runtime-arg -classpath --runtime-arg  --debuggable --instruction-set=arm --instruction-set-features=smp,div,atomic_ldrd_strd --runtime-arg -Xrelocate --boot-image=/system/framework/boot.art --runtime-arg -Xms64m --runtime-arg -Xmx512m --compiler-filter=speed --instruction-set-variant=cortex-a15 --instruction-set-features=default --dex-file=/data/app/com.example.googlecamera2-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk --oat-file=/data/dalvik-cache/arm/data@app@com.example.googlecamera2-1@split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk@classes.dex) because non-0 exit status
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.googlecamera2-1/lib/arm
I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
W/art: Before Android 4.1, method android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter android.support.graphics.drawable.VectorDrawableCompat.updateTintFilter(android.graphics.PorterDuffColorFilter, android.content.res.ColorStateList, android.graphics.PorterDuff$Mode) would have incorrectly overridden the package-private method in android.graphics.drawable.Drawable
D/TextView: setTypeface with style : 0
D/ViewRootImpl: #1 mView = com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView{bb95551 I.E...... R.....ID 0,0-0,0}
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
D/libEGL: loaded /vendor/lib/egl/libGLES_mali.so
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xe0f717c4
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [720x1280]-format:1
I/CameraManagerGlobal: Connecting to camera service
I/CameraManager: Using legacy camera HAL.
D/libGLESv1: DTS_GLAPI : DTS is not allowed for Package : com.example.googlecamera2
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state CONFIGURING
I/RequestThread-0: Configure outputs: 2 surfaces configured.
D/Camera: app passed NULL surface
I/RequestThread-0: configureOutputs - set take picture size to 4128x3096
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xddaff404
D/mali_winsys: new_window_surface returns 0x3000,  [960x720]-format:1
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
I/RequestQueue: Repeating capture request set.
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
    Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
D/ViewRootImpl: MSG_RESIZED_REPORT: ci=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) vi=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) or=1
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported
E/RECT: 720 960
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@370aa78 time:79076526
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xddaff2f4
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state CAPTURING
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xe0f71614
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xddaff2f4
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xe0f71614
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xddaff2f4
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xddaff2f4
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xddaff2f4
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xddaff2f4
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xddaff2f4
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xddaff2f4
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xddaff2f4
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xddaff2f4
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xddaff2f4
D/libEGL: eglInitialize EGLDisplay = 0xddaff2f4
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
    Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
    convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
    Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
    convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported
I/RequestQueue: Repeating capture request cancelled.
I/RequestThread-0: Flushing all pending requests.
E/RequestQueue: cancel failed: no repeating request exists.
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestMetadata - control.awbRegions setting is not supported, ignoring value
    Only received metering rectangles with weight 0.
W/LegacyRequestMapper: convertRequestToMetadata - Ignoring android.lens.focusDistance false, only 0.0f is supported
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state CAPTURING
I/RequestThread-0: Received jpeg.
    Producing jpeg buffer...
D/ImageReader_JNI: ImageReader_lockedImageSetup: Receiving JPEG in HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888 buffer.
I/CameraDeviceState: Legacy camera service transitioning to state IDLE
D/libEGL: eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xddaff384
D/libEGL: eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xddaff49c
    eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xddaff424
    eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xddaff424
    eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xddaff424
    eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xddaff424
    eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xddaff424
    eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xddaff424
    eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xddaff424
    eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xddaff424
    eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xddaff424
    eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xddaff424
    eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xddaff424
    eglTerminate EGLDisplay = 0xddaff424
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-14265-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-14265-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-14265-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-14265-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
    [SurfaceTexture-1-14265-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
    [SurfaceTexture-1-14265-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
    [SurfaceTexture-1-14265-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-14265-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-14265-1] cancelBuffer: BufferQueue has been abandoned
E/BufferQueueProducer: [SurfaceTexture-1-14265-1] setBufferCount: BufferQueue has been abandoned
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.googlecamera2 time:79081932
A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0xdba03ff8 in tid 14345 (CameraBackgroun)
Application terminated.
```

---

**I don't understand what's with that SIGSEGV error in the end. It appears most of the time, but not always.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I finally figured it out myself.
*The problem was the `overlay` that I was drawing on the camera preview.*

When I closed the camera and tried leaving the activity, the `preview size` variable likely got destroyed due to which the canvas failed to access its width and height which were necessary to draw the overlay.
So I just had to exit the `onDraw()` in the `Rectangle` class, if the camera was being closed and that fixed the issue.

I achieved this by having a simple boolean variable which I passed to the Rectangle class. If it was set to false, then the rectangle was not drawn.

Before changing the activity, I just set the `camerOn` to `false` and then called the `onDraw()` which simply returned without drawing the rectangle, as the variable was false and the SIGSEGV exception was sorted.